My smart contract won't compile
I always receive this message Nothing to compile whenever I compile, what could be the reason?
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.20;

import "./PriceConverter.sol";
import {AggregatorV3Interface} from "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/shared/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

// error Fundme__NotEnoughUSD();
error Fundme__NotOwner();

contract FundMe {
    uint256 public constant MINIMUM_USD = 100 * 1e18;
    AggregatorV3Interface private s_priceFeed;
    using PriceConverter for uint256;
    address[] public s_funders;
    mapping(address => uint) public s_addressToAmountFunded;
    address public immutable i_owner;

    modifier onlyOwner() {
        if (msg.sender != i_owner) revert Fundme__NotOwner();
        _;
    }

    constructor(address priceFeedAddress) {
        s_priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface(priceFeedAddress);
    }

    function fund() public payable {
        // if (msg.value.getConversionRate(priceFeed) < MINIMUM_USD)
        //     revert Fundme__NotEnoughUSD();
        require(
            msg.value.getConversionRate(s_priceFeed) >= MINIMUM_USD, // Using priceFeed to get the conversion rate of msg.value(ETH)
            "Minimum of 100 USD is required!"
        );
        s_funders.push(msg.sender);
        s_addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] = msg.value;
    }

    // As the owner is withdrawing the funds, the smart contract is resetting and ready for new funds
    function withdraw() public onlyOwner {
        (bool success, ) = i_owner.call{value: address(this).balance}("");
        require(success);

        address[] memory funders = s_funders;

        for (
            uint256 fundersIndex = 0;
            fundersIndex < s_funders.length;
            fundersIndex++
        ) {
            address funder = funders[fundersIndex];
            s_addressToAmountFunded[funder] = 0; // The amount funded by each funder is reset to 0
        }

        s_funders = new address[](0);
    }
}


Because your artifacts are already built, so unless there are any new changes to the contracts, it keeps showing "Nothing to compile" whenever you compile using forge compile or npx hardhat compile.
If you want to recompile it and build artifacts folder again without doing any changes to the contracts, then you can just clean it using forge clean or npx hardhat clean, depending on whether you’re using foundry or hardhat.
After the artifacts being cleaned, when you compile again, it’ll compile all the contracts and build the artifacts again.
